# Why isn't this global variable found if it's defined in the main?

Tags: python, exception, global-variables

I made this simple script to try out something. Basically, it should catch any exception that occurs during the running of an application and disconnect from the server.

```
import sys
import traceback
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        # Generate exception
        raise Exception('Oh no!')
    def foo(self):
        print('Bar')

def error_handler(etype, value, tb):
    global ex
    error_msg = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(etype, value, tb))
    print(error_msg)
    ex.foo()
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.excepthook = error_handler
    app = QApplication([])
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

How come the variable can't be found by the error handler if it's defined inside the main?

Comment: What if the exception occurs before the line where `ex` is defined?

Comment: @khelwood I've updated the question with a self-contained example, but you hit the nail on the head. The exception is occurring when *defining* `ex`, so it's never created. How could I handle these exceptions too, then?

Comment: If you want to handle exceptions that occur before `ex` is defined, you'll have to write your handler so it does not assume that `ex` is defined. Or assign it to something else first.

Comment: Pragmatically, I would just set `ex = None` even before the `sys.excepthook = error_handler`.  Then you can easily handle the case that `ex is None` in the handler.  You could of course also use `try`/`except` when accessing `ex` but to do that properly you should put the access of `ex` alone into the try-clause and that looks weird.

Comment: That sounds sensible, thanks. @khelwood, feel free to write a short answer so I can accept it, as you were the first one to spot the mistake in the code.

Comment: @Tendero Why have you eliminated the other question? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem was that the exception was being raised before `ex` was assigned to anything.

If an exception needs to be handled before `ex` is defined, the handler needs not to assume that it can use `ex`.

A simple way to handle it might be to set `ex` to `None` before it is ready, and check it in the handler.

```
def error_handler(etype, value, tb):
    error_msg = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(etype, value, tb))
    print(error_msg)
    if ex: # Check if ex is ready
        ex.foo()
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ex = None
    sys.excepthook = error_handler
    app = QApplication([])
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought `error_handler` was executed before you defined `ex`.Because i tried this:

```
def function():
    global hello 
    print(hello)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func = function
    hello = "world"
    func() #world
```

So you need to defined `ex` before using it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ex = Window() #defined it first
    sys.excepthook = error_handler
    app = QApplication([])
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: That's not going to solve the problem if `Window()` is the source of the exception (as it is in the OP's code).